# Why use a negated empty set in a Regular Expression rather than .?

Tags: regex

I came across the following RE recently:

```
(?:<div class="something[^>]+?>[^]+<span class="somethingelse">([\d.])+|<div id="anotherthing[^"]+" class="[^"]*andanother)
```

The set `[^]` is valid in JavaScript but not in PCRE. My understanding of it is that it will match "anything not in the set". Since the set is empty, it must be matching anything (one or more times). So why would someone use `[^]+` rather than simply `.+` ? Is there some very subtle difference, perhaps to do with line endings?

Comment: You should ask whoever that wrote that code...

Comment: In my opinion this is a more appropriate place to ask the question : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Sweeper I don't know who that is - but maybe they're on SO.....

Answer (score 3):

`.` does not match line endings by default. You can enable the `DOTALL` option (e.g `/.+/s`)  to make it match line endings as well.

Comment: Okay regarding . not matching line endings, but how does . differ from [^]?

Comment: With `DOTALL` enabled, `[^]` and `.` are equivalent.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This is actually the correct answer. Regardless of how good of an idea that is, `[^]+` matches any sequence also including newlines, while `.+` won't. +1 from me.